# Simple implementation websockets on Azure

Tags: c#, json, wcf, azure

I have a azure cloud service project that hosts a few services (myService.svc, generated from a wsdl file via "Adding new service reference").

This works well and is really simple to handle.

Example of service declaration :

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="myBehaviour" name="myService">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CentralSystemServiceSoap" contract="CentralSystemService" />
      </service>

[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute("CentralSystemService")]
public interface CentralSystemService
{

}
```

But some of my devices now require websockets protocol using JSON.

I've read a lot about how websockets work and I've found a lot of different implementations which seem to be way too complicated but mainly they were all completely different. I've looked for implementations that would be closer to WCF services. But all the examples were not including the handshake part for example.

My project is published on azure (cloud service instance) and all my previous svc have to be still working.

Can I keep everything in the same project and create my websockets JSON services in the same ?
I ask the question because most of the examples I've found were including a Main function to open the listener of the server and I've not been able to set a startup main method in my Cloud project.

Which kind of implementation would you recommend me ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

When using NetHttpBinding binding, we can communicate between WCF service and client over WebSockets by a callback contract. Steps below are for your reference.

Step 1, In web.config, we need to configure NetHttpBinding as protocolMapping.

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="netHttpBinding"/>
  <add scheme="https" binding="netHttpsBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

Step 2, Create service contract with callback.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task SendMessageBack(string message);
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IServiceCallback))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task DoSomething(string parameter);
}
```

Step 3, In WCF service, we can get the instance of service callback and use it to send message to client.

```
public class MySocketService : IService
{
    public async Task DoSomething(string parameter)
    {
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceCallback>();
        var random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = 2;

        while (((IChannel)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
        {
            await callback.SendMessageBack("Call back message:" + randomNumber);
            randomNumber += random.Next(10);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Step 4, In client, we need to implement the service callback interface and use it to receive the messages from service.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new InstanceContext(new CallbackHandler());
        var client = new ServiceClient(context);
        client.DoSomething("a message");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


public class CallbackHandler : IServiceCallback
{
    void IServiceCallback.SendMessageBack(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

[image]

For more information, link below is for your reference.

[How to: Create a WCF Service that Communicates over WebSockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-wcf-service-that-communicates-over-websockets)

Comment: Thank you ! However I don't have access to the client, the client is a device I have to communicate with it. + I don't understand how the handshake part works in your code/link.

Comment: If you need to perform more control on data transfer, I suggest you create a websocket server by a .NET library named [SuperSocket](http://supersocket.net/). It has built-in JSON support and supports mutiple hosting environment like windows service, console application and web site.